# Correct typing for apply method with console.log?

Tags: typescript

I've written the below class to capture the `console.log` function in my app so I can review the logs on devices where I can't easily access the browser console and so later I can bundle the captured logs when reporting errors.

In order to get it working, I've had to add `ts-ignore` like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
oldDebug.apply(console, arguments);
```

Without the `ts-ignore` directive, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any?, ...any[]]'.
```

Here is the code I'm using for capturing the logs:

```
let oldLog: typeof console.log;

export type LogLevel = "log"|"debug"|"warn"|"error";

export interface ConsoleLogMessage{
  level: LogLevel,
  arguments: IArguments,
}

export function interceptConsoleLogs(){
  if( oldLog ){
    throw new Error("log functions already intercepted");
  }

  oldLog = console.log;
  window.console.log = function(){
    storeLogMessage("log", arguments);
    // @ts-ignore
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
  };

  ...
  debug, warn, error
  ...
}

export function getCurrentLogMessages(): ConsoleLogMessage[]{
  return logStorage.slice(0);
}

const maxLogs = 100;
const logStorage: ConsoleLogMessage[] = [];

function storeLogMessage(level: LogLevel, args: IArguments){
  if (logStorage.length >= maxLogs) {
    logStorage.shift();
  }
  logStorage.push({level: level, arguments: args});
}
```

How should my types look if I want to do these `apply` calls without adding `ts-ignore`?

---

Environment:
My app is a `create-react-app` project upgraded to typescript 3.6.3, with the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles without errors on http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ (even after removing ts-ignore) Try reproducing the issue there and also update your question with the version of TypeScript you're using and your tsconfig.json

Comment: @lukasgeiter I think there might be something weird about the setup at typescriptlang.org, when I pasted the code into https://repl.it/languages/typescript - it shows the error I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `arguments` is not really an array.

It's an "array-like" object which [MDN describes like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> "Array-like" means that `arguments` has a `length` property and properties indexed from zero, but it doesn't have `Array`'s built-in methods like `forEach()` and `map()`.

---

In strict mode, the compiler performs strict type checking on the parameters of `apply` which are not satisfied by the type of `arguments` because it is not actually an array.

As you've already found out yourself, the best solution is to use [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters). This is a good thing, because rest parameters are preferred over `arguments` anyway.

It also makes it easy to explicitly specify some parameters and just collect the rest in an array:

```js
window.console.log = function(message?: any, ...args: any[]){
  storeLogMessage({level: "log", message: message, args: args});
  oldLog.apply(console, [message, ...args]);
};
```

Note that you could also use `.call` instead of `.apply` now and pass the rest parameter directly without first constructing an array:

```js
window.console.log = function(message?: any, ...args: any[]){
  storeLogMessage({level: "log", message: message, args: args});
  oldLog.call(console, message, ...args);
};
```

---

The strict checking of `apply`, `call` and `bind` is controlled with the compiler option [`strictBindCallApply`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply). It is automatically enabled with `strict: true`. This was also the reason why there were no errors on [typescriptlang.org/play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). The playground has some of the strict options enabled but not all of them. `strictBindCallApply` is one of the disabled ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with that works without needing the `ts-ignore` annotation.

```
window.console.log = function(message?: any, ...args: any[]){
  storeLogMessage({level: "log", message: message, args: args});
  oldLog.apply(console, [message, ...args]);
};
```